# Using Watir Webdriver with Google ChromeFrame (GCF)

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, google-chrome-frame

I am using Watir Webdriver to run integration tests against a number of browsers.  Some of the pages we use include the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />` so that the page uses the ChromeFrame plug in.  This is necessary as some of the javascript we use is just to heavy for some of the older versions of IE we need to support.  When we run the Watir tests without Chrome frame the tests execute ok.  With the meta tag they all fail immediately with the error `Unable to find element with xpath` as soon as we test for anything.  Obviously ChromeFrame is not exposing the same interface back to Webdriver as IE does.  Is there any possible configuration I can do to test ChromeFrame in this manner?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question ?

Comment: No, I have not solved this problem.

Comment: Thank you :(
Any way around this ?